# How to fix this error in laravel 8.10.1 : Undefined constant "App\Exports\id"

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I'm getting this error while calling the export function of laravel Excel.
Can anyone help me solve this error or why am I getting it???

Laravel Version: 8.10.1

Laravel Excel Package Version: 3.1

[image: Error Screenshot]

My Code in Controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\ProductInventoryExport;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function ProductInventory()
    {
        return Excel::download(new \App\Exports\ProductInventoryExport, 'ProductInventory.xlsx');

    }
}
```

My Code in Export Class File:

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\AttributeValue;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Subcategory;
use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer;
use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;
use Carbon\Carbon;

Writer::macro('setCreator', function (Writer $writer, string $creator) {
    $writer->getDelegate()->getProperties()->setCreator($creator);
});


Sheet::macro('styleCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, array $style) {
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray($style);
});

Sheet::macro('setOrientation', function (Sheet $sheet, $orientation) {
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation);
});


class ProductInventoryExport implements FromArray, ShouldAutoSize, WithHeadings, WithStyles
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\collection
    */

    // STYLES

    public $columns = [id, image, name, slug, product_type, size, colour, tax_percent, cost_price, regular_price, sale_price, SKU, quantity, stock_status, sold, purchase_limit, featured, short_description, description, category_id, subcategory_id, created_at, updated_at];

    public $HeadingStyle = [
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_MEDIUM,
            ],
        ],
        'alignment' => [
            'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
            'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        ],
        'font' => [
            'bold' => true,
            'size' => 12,
        ],
    ];

    public $ColumnStyle = [
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_MEDIUM,
            ],
        ],
        'alignment' => [
            'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        ],
        'font' => [
            'bold' => true,
            'size' => 8,
        ],
    ];

    public $CellStyle = [
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
            ],
        ],
        'alignment' => [
            'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        ],
        'font' => [
            'bold' => false,
            'size' => 8,
        ],
    ];

    // FUNCTIONS

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('products');
        // $ar = [];
        // foreach($columns as $column)
        // {
        //     array_push($ar, ucwords(trans(preg_replace('/__*/', ' ', $column))));
        // }
        return [
            ['Rojanic Bangladesh'],
            ['In Stock Products - '.Carbon::now()->month.' '.Carbon::now()->year],
            ['ID', 'Image', 'Name', 'Slug', 'Type', 'Size', 'Colour', 'Vat Percent', 'Cost Price', 'Regular Price', 'Sale Price', 'Barcode', 'Left Quantity', 'Stock', 'Sold', 'Purchase Limit', 'Featured', 'Short Description', 'Description', 'Category', 'Sub Category', 'Created At', 'Last Updated'],
            // $ar
        ];
    }

    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {

        $columnTill = 'a';
        foreach(Schema::getColumnListing('products') as $colum)
        {
            $columnTill++;
        }
        --$columnTill;
        $productCount = Product::all()->count();
        $sheet->mergeCells('A1:'.$columnTill.'1', Worksheet::MERGE_CELL_CONTENT_MERGE);
        $sheet->mergeCells('A2:'.$columnTill.'2', Worksheet::MERGE_CELL_CONTENT_MERGE);
        $sheet->getStyle('A1:'.$columnTill.'1')->applyFromArray($this->HeadingStyle);
        $sheet->getStyle('A2:'.$columnTill.'2')->applyFromArray($this->HeadingStyle);
        $sheet->getStyle('A3:'.$columnTill.'3')->applyFromArray($this->ColumnStyle);
        $sheet->getStyle('A4:'.$columnTill.Product::all()->count()+3)->applyFromArray($this->CellStyle);
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        $ready = [];
        foreach(Product::all() as $product)
        {
            $part = [];
            $attributes = AttributeValue::where('product_id',$product->id)->get();
            $productCategory = null;
            $productSubCategory = null;
            if($product->category_id)
            {
                $productCategory = Category::find($product->category_id);
            }
            if($product->subcategory_id)
            {
                $productCategory = Subcategory::find($product->subcategory_id);
            }
            if($attributes->count() > 0)
            {
                foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                {
                    array_push($part,
                        $product->id,
                        $attribute->image ? $attribute->image : $product->image,
                        $product->name,
                        $product->slug,
                        $product->product_type,
                        $attribute->size,
                        $attribute->colour,
                        $product->tax_percent,
                        $attribute->cost_price ? $attribute->cost_price : $product->cost_price,
                        $attribute->regular_price ? $attribute->regular_price : $product->regular_price,
                        $attribute->sale_price ? $attribute->sale_price : $product->sale_price,
                        $product->SKU,
                        $attribute->quantity,
                        $attribute->quantity > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out Of Stock',
                        OrderItem::where('product_id',$product->id)->where('attribute_id',$attribute->id)->count(),
                        $product->purchase_limit,
                        $product->featured,
                        $product->short_description,
                        $product->description,
                        $productCategory,
                        $productSubCategory,
                        $attribute->created_at,
                        $attribute->updated_at
                    );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($part,
                    $product->id,
                    $product->image,
                    $product->name,
                    $product->slug,
                    $product->product_type,
                    'N/A',
                    'N/A',
                    $product->tax_percent,
                    $product->cost_price,
                    $product->regular_price,
                    $product->sale_price,
                    $product->SKU,
                    $product->quantity,
                    $product->quantity > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out Of Stock',
                    OrderItem::where('product_id',$product->id)->count(),
                    $product->purchase_limit,
                    $product->featured,
                    $product->short_description,
                    $product->description,
                    $productCategory,
                    $productSubCategory,
                    $product->created_at,
                    $product->updated_at
                );
            }
            array_push($ready, $part);
        }
        return
            $ready
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
public $columns = [id, image, name, slug, product_type, size, colour, tax_percent, cost_price, regular_price, sale_price, SKU, quantity, stock_status, sold, purchase_limit, featured, short_description, description, category_id, subcategory_id, created_at, updated_at];
```

you should enclose each array elements using single or double quotes. If you don't, PHP treats them as constants, and since there's no 'id' constant in the `App\Exports` namespace, PHP throws that error.